# React Native build failed while executing task > Path is not a readable directory

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I used Windows Subsystem for Linux, maybe this is the problem? I will be glad of any help, I will provide the information you need.

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
320 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 319 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Path 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\react-native-app\node_modules\unimodules-sensors-interface\android\build\intermediates\compiled_local_resources\debug\out' is not a readable directory.
```

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the `react-native-app\android\.gradle` folder fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

rebuild the project to solve this issue.

run the below command in the terminal to delete the .gradle file.

*rm -rf android/.gradle
rm -rf .gradle
rm -rf ~/.gradle
./gradlew clean*

[github URL](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1142#issuecomment-611375415)